# share login between two different websites

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, authentication, shared, form-authentication

So I am having two different websites that use database sessions for login both have the same application name but for some reason I can't maintain login when I redirect from website A to website B

below are configuration for both website

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
      <!-- timeout should be 60 minutes (as per feedback from users).  The default value = 60 min -->
      <forms loginUrl="/secure/login" defaultUrl="~/Default.aspx" name="Name" enableCrossAppRedirects="false" protection="All" requireSSL="false" timeout="480" slidingExpiration="true" />
    </authentication> 


   <add name="AspNetSqlProfileProvider" connectionStringName="SqlServerConnectionString" applicationName="/" type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider" />
```

I am guessing I need to some how create the authentication cookie under domain B but donno how without passing the login username and password ( Note, its not even an option)

Comment: Are the 2 sites on different domains? aka example1.com and example2.com?

Comment: yes and different servers too

Comment: Then no, it is not possible

Comment: Cookies can't be shared between domains.

Comment: Else your site could check the cookie from facebook for example. Big no no in privacy world. If you wish to share the cookies, the applications need to be on the same domain or on subdomains of the same domain cq one.example.com and two.example.com

Comment: but they both use the same SQL server, isnt that the idea of database session

Comment: No and yes,, to indicate what session is being used, the server places a cookie in the request. Else the server doesn't know what session to use.

Comment: ok so is there away to pass the session ID as parameter in redirection ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135786/discussion-between-miroo-and-synercoder).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the authentication cookie configuration add domain=".domain.com"